# CSS height: 100% not working on inline-block element although parent div has height

Tags: html, css, height

I have a div that has two child divs inside it, like so:

```
<div id="cartgrid" style="display:inline-block">
    <div class="cart-left">
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="cart-right">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.cart-left` holds a table of items, while `.cart-right` only has a few buttons, so `.cart-left` is always taller than `.cart-right`; the height of the parent div is determined by the height of `.cart-left`. I want `.cart-right` to have the same height as `.cart-left`, so I gave it `height:100%`, but even though its parents (`#cartgrid`) has a height value, `height:100%` does nothing.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjuzh07n/

Comment: 100% height only works if the parent has a defined height.

Comment: Offtopic: `#cartgrid` exists twice... an id should be unique

Answer (score 0):

A bit dirty, but that's how I would fix it.

```
#cartgrid {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
  .cart-right {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Hope it might help.